# Proposed proof Decomposition theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital Banach algebra.
I want to prove that if $a \in \mathcal{A}$ and spectrum $\sigma(a) = \sigma_{1} \cup \sigma_{2}$ where $\sigma_{1} \cap \sigma_{2} = \emptyset$, $\sigma_{1},~\sigma_{2} \neq \emptyset$. Then there exists non-trivial idempotents $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$. When $a_{k} = aE_{k}$ we have $\sigma(a_{k}) = \sigma_{k}.$

Proof:

Let
$$g_{k}(z) =
\begin{cases}  & 1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{ if }  z \in \Omega_{k} \supseteq \sigma_{k},\\ &0 ~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if } z \in \Omega_{j} \supseteq \sigma_{j}~~\text{where }j \neq k. \end{cases}
$$

where $\Omega_{k} \supseteq \sigma_{k}$ are open $\Omega_{1} \cap \Omega_{2} = \emptyset$ and where $k \in \{1,2 \}$. Then $g_{k} \in \text{Hol}(a)$. Further let $E_{k} = g_{k}(a) \in \mathcal{A}$ then $$E_{1} + E_{2} = (g_{1} + g_{2})(a) = 1 \in \mathcal{A}.$$

Let $a_{k} = E_{k}a$, if $f(z) = z$ on some $\Omega \supseteq \sigma(a)$, then $f \in \text{Hol}(a)$ and $$a_{k} = E_{k}a = (g_{k} \cdot f)(a) = (f\cdot g_{k})(a) = a E_{k}.$$

Hence $E_{k}$ commutes with $a$. Further, from the spectral mapping theorem, we have $\sigma(a_{k}) = \sigma((g_{k} \cdot f)(a)) = (g_{k} \cdot f)(\sigma(a))$.

But we have
$$(g_{k} \cdot f)(z) =
\begin{cases}  & z ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{ if }  z \in \Omega_{k} \supseteq \sigma_{k},\\ &0 ~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if } z \in \Omega_{j} \supseteq \sigma_{j}~~\text{where }j \neq k. \end{cases}
$$

This implies $(g_{k} \cdot f)(\sigma(a))  =\sigma_{k} \implies \sigma(a_{k}) = \sigma_{k}$.

Comment: Please clarify your notation.

Comment: @gerw What is unclear?

Comment: $\mathcal{A}$, $\sigma(\cdot)$, ...

Comment: @gerw Oh yeah will add that now.

Comment: Everything looks good, except for one problem: You can pick up $0$ in the spectrum for $\sigma_k$ (why?) And that can break $\sigma(a_k)=\sigma_k$ unless $0 \in \sigma_k$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Yeah that's true, thanks for checking.